# Derivative of normal unit vector in frenet coordinates

Tags: vectors, partial-derivative, frenet-frame

I am trying to understand the derivation of some formulas in the paper Motion Control of Wheeled Mobile Robots by C. Samson in Springer Handbook of Robotics (2008).

[image]

Currently I am stuck at the following formula:

$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{OP}}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial \mathbf{OP}_s}{\partial t} + \dot d \mathbf{j}_s - dc(s)\dot s \mathbf{i}_s
$$

where $c(s)$ is the curvature of curve $C$ parametrized by the curvilinear abscissa $s$.

In the formula above I do not understant how the last term $dc(s)\dot s \mathbf{i}_s$ is obtained.

I think all begins by defining the vector $\mathbf{OP}$ and deriving it using the product rule:

$$
\mathbf{OP} = \mathbf{OP}_s + d \mathbf{j}_s
$$

$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{OP}}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial \mathbf{OP}_s}{\partial t} + \dot d \mathbf{j}_s + d \frac{\partial \mathbf{j}_s}{\partial t}
$$

**Could you please tell me if my derivation of the formula is correct so far?**

My next problem is that I don't know what's the result of deriving the normal unit vector $\mathbf{j}_s$ with respect to time $t$. 
**How does it relate to the curvature $c(s)$ and the velocity in $s$ direction?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the [frenet formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) and assuming a torsion $\tau$ of zero because we are only moving in the plane.
According to the formulas, the time derivative of the normal vector $\mathbf{j}_s$ is

$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{j}_s}{\partial t} = (\tau \mathbf{k_s} - c \mathbf{i}_s)\left| \frac{\partial \mathbf{OP}_s}{\partial t} \right| = -c \dot s \mathbf{i}_s
$$

where $\mathbf{k_s}$ is the binormal unit vector of the torsion $\tau$, which is zero in the plane.

However, I am not really sure where these formulas come from but this is another question. It is similar to deriving a tangent vector which yields the vector perpendicular to it.